# Making a goroutine/channel that drops data when no connection available

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm new to goroutines and trying to work out the idiomatic way to organise this code. My program will generate async status events that I want to transmit to a server over a websocket. Right now I have a global channel `messagesToServer` to receive the status messages. The idea is it that will send the data if we currently have a websocket open, or quietly drop it if the connection to the server is currently closed or unavailable.

Relevant snippets are below. I don't really like the non-blocking send - if for some reason my writer goroutine took a while to process a message I think it could end up dropping a quick second message for no reason?

But if I use a blocking send, `sendStatusToServer` could block something that shouldn't be blocked if the connection is offline. I could try to track connected/disconnected state but if a message was sent at the same time as the disconnection occurred I think there would be a race condition.

Is there a tidy way I can write this?

```
var (
    messagesToServer chan common.StationStatus
)

// ...
func sendStatusToServer(msg common.StationStatus) {
    // Must be non-blocking in case we're not connected
    select {
    case messagesToServer <- msg:
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
// ...

// after making websocket connection
            log.Println("Connected to central server");
            finished := make(chan struct{})

            // Writer
            go func() {
                for {
                    select {
                    case msg := <-messagesToServer:
                        var buff bytes.Buffer
                        enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buff)
                        err = enc.Encode(msg)
                        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.BinaryMessage, buff.Bytes()); // ignore errors by design
                    case <-finished:
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }()

            // Reader as busy loop on this goroutine
            for {
                messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()
```

Comment: Use a mutex to prevent the race described in the question.

Comment: You need to have a way to figure out if the writer goroutine is at work and time out if needed - you can retry sending the message till the timeout.

Comment: There is no simple answer because this isn't a simple problem. You need to work through *exactly* what you want to happen in each scenario, including how long you're willing to buffer pending sends for, how much memory you're willing to consume on pending sends, etc.